# Does "Ocaña" mean something in Spanish and more specifically, what does it mean to be the "Ocaña de España?"

Tags: definiciones, proverbios

I saw this phrase "Ocaña de España" in the following article:

**"[El rótulo de ‘El Hormiguero’ sobre Aitana que ha sido aplaudido en redes sociales](https://okdiario.com/happyfm/rotulo-hormiguero-sobre-aitana-que-sido-aplaudido-redes-sociales-4248692?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_campaign=ok&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1560503526),"**
*— OK Diario*

If you can't link to the article or want to see what I'm referring to directly, see the excerpt below:

> ... Aitana visitaba el plató de ‘El Hormiguero’ para presentar su nuevo disco ‘Spoiler’. Allí se mostró muy cómoda en compañía de Pablo Motos y regaló a los telespectadores una divertida y bonita velada. Pero hubo algo que no pasó desapercibido para los seguidores de la cantante, y es que como es habitual en el formato a la hora de la entrevista el programa pone un rótulo con el nombre del invitado y una frase cómica que suele ser un juego de palabras.
>
> En el caso de Aitana fue la siguiente: **“Aitana, la Ocaña de España”** haciendo alusión al refranero español y consiguiendo el aplauso de la audiencia en redes sociales.

---

**¿Ocaña significa algo en español?  Y más específicamente, ¿qué significa ser la «Ocaña de España»?**

Vi esta frase «Ocaña de España» en el siguiente artículo:

**"[El rótulo de ‘El Hormiguero’ sobre Aitana que ha sido aplaudido en redes sociales](https://okdiario.com/happyfm/rotulo-hormiguero-sobre-aitana-que-sido-aplaudido-redes-sociales-4248692?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_campaign=ok&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1560503526),"**
*— OK Diario*

Si no puede enlazar al artículo, o quiere ver lo que estoy refiriendo directamente, véase arriba (en la sección escrita en inglés).

Comment: Note that Aitana's full name is [Aitana Ocaña Morales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitana_(cantante)). Regarding the sentence itself, it makes me think about the sentence _ser la caña de España_, which means to be great.

Comment: Yep, it is a wordplay. Now, why do we say *la caña de España*? Maybe it is just because of the alliteration.

Comment: @Gorpik  Did you mean rhyme instead of alliteration?

Comment: Yeah, probably. The meaning of the English *alliteration* is a bit different from the Spanish *aliteración*; in any case, I meant that the repetition of sounds led to it. Same as we say *Maroto el de la moto*, *toma del frasco, Carrasco*, *más pedo que Alfredo*...

Comment: @Gorpik  Sorry if I might have come across as a critical jerk.  I suppose I just have a narrow concept of certain literary terms.  For me, rhymes are rhymes, but after having reviewed the definition of alliteration (and even more so, [**consonance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_consonance)), I can see that there is room for overlap.

Comment: @LisaBeck You did not, don't worry :) Well, this is a rhyme between two immediate words, if we don't take into account unstressed words. In English, this is used in expressions like *Howdy dowdy* or names like *Chilly Willy* or *Nash the Slash*. But I don't know what is the specific name for this figure.

Comment: @Gorpik I think it may be referred to by some as "nonsense reduplication," a term I had not heard of until I got curious about the word "zoot suit" one day and posted a question about it over on the English Language & Usage SE.  If this interests you at all, you can link to it [**here**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269941/does-anyone-happen-to-know-more-about-the-word-zoot-and-this-use-of-speech-cal).  Less specifically, I suppose such phrases could be considered both rhyme and consonance, especially since your examples are a bit different than "zoot suit."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a play on words based on the idiom *"ser la caña"* or *"ser la caña de España"*, which means "to be really good":

> *Este coche me encanta, es la caña.*
>   I love this car, it's very good.
>
> *Mi perro es la caña, ¡hasta sabe tirar la basura!*
>   My dog is really great, he can even take the trash out!
>
> *¡Vale ya con el nuevo restaurante! ¡Ni que fuera la caña de España!*
>   Enough already with the new restaurant! As if it was the best thing ever!

The actress's (first) surname is "Ocaña", hence the play on words between *caña* and *Ocaña*.

Comment: ¡Perfecto!  ¡Gracias!